# change react Build cofiguration

Tags: php, reactjs, server, build, create-react-app

I have a project that contains a multi stepping form and as per customer request, I used React to create it. The problem now is the customer need a plain HTML template to upload it to his server which has a system to control content by Php variables added to the plain HTML file. And, react build does not produce plain HTML code but most are JS code, is there a way or a method to produce full HTML code or not?

Answer (score 0):

I don't particularly understand your needs, but my guess is that you need webpack to generate the html files according to your template, in which case you can set the `template` for `html-webpack-plugin`

```
 // webpack.config.js

 module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/main.js",
  plugins: [
    ...
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Hello",
      filename: "hello.html",
      template: "./template/hello.html",
    }),
    ...
  ],
...
}
```

Comment: Well, Thank you for your answer. Where can I add this file ?

Comment: @AhmedElbessfy Is the project generated with create-react-app?
If so you can use the `npm-run-eject` command as described in the official documentation at [https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts#npm-run-eject](create-react-app)

Comment: **Note that this operation is irreversible**

Comment: Ok I found it is irreversible, but after I execute this command, where to add the webpack configuration ??